# unable to create a context in swift file

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I need to fetch some data from CoreData and need to do it frequently and hence trying to create utility class for it.
When I try to create context for it, it gives me error and below is the code.
I added a new .swift file and pasted below code

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData

class armyDataSource{

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext


}
```

really not sure what wrong I'm doing it here.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to create a wrappper class for core data manager you can write class like given below code in a swift file with your implementation.

```
 import UIKit
 import CoreData
class CoreDataManager {


static let sharedManager = CoreDataManager()
private init() {} // Prevent clients from creating another instance.

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    /*
     The persistent container for the application. This implementation
     creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
     application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
     error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
     */
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "StackOF")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

            /*
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
             * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
             * The device is out of space.
             * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
             */
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initialize these properties like that in a class. You need to do this initialization in a method, best in the init call.

> Cannot use instance member 'appDelegate' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

So this means that you cannot use a property to initialize another property because this is all done before the init is called and self is fully available.

Try this instead:

```
class armyDataSource {

    let appDelegate: UIApplicationDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext

    init() {
        appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
}
```